# Using Fetch Module to Backup Files Offsite - Error " file not found "

Tags: ansible, fetch

These Ansible tasks are supposed to first, find the correct file(s) and register their path. In this case files ending with '.tar.gz'. Second is to move those file(s) matches offsite for backup.

```
- name: Find and register {{ domain_name }} archive
  find:
    paths: /home/backups/{{ domain_name }}/archive/
    patterns: '*.tar.gz'
  register: tar_file
  tags: bkup.offsite

- name: Fetch {{ domain_name }} archive for offsite backup
  fetch:
    src: /home/{{ domain_name }}/archive/{{ item }}
    dest: '{{ store_path }}'
    fail_on_missing: yes
  with_items: '{{ tar_file }}'
  tags: bkup.offsite
```

My error:

> failed: [45.63.35.46] (item=files) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "files", "msg": "file not found: /home/backups/tester/archive/files"}
>   failed: [45.63.35.46] (item=changed) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "changed", "msg": "file not found: /home/backups/tester/archive/changed"}
>   failed: [45.63.35.46] (item=msg) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "msg", "msg": "file not found: /home/backups/tester/archive/msg"}
>   failed: [45.63.35.46] (item=matched) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "matched", "msg": "file not found: /home/backups/tester/archive/matched"}
>   failed: [45.63.35.46] (item=examined) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "examined", "msg": "file not found: /home/backups/tester/archive/examined"}
>   failed: [45.63.35.46] (item=failed) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "failed", "msg": "file not found: /home/backups/tester/archive/failed"}

I have double-checked that there is a file in the path with .tar.gz that should be matching and moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `register:` for **every** ansible task consists of a few top-level keys related to the task execution itself, including `changed`, `failed`, `msg`, etc, plus whatever return values from the task. The thing you are after is `files`, as documented in [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/find_module.html#return-values), as you can see in the `item=files` error from your attempt; thus:

```
- debug:
    msg: look, the tar file is actually {{ item.path }}
  with_items: '{{ tar_file.files }}'
```

Comment: I used debug for the first time, thank you. I have it working now!